# Blender render output is completely white

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

In my layout view, everything looks perfectly fine, but when I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> in Blender the render output is completely white:

Layout view:

[image: layout view]
Render View:

[image: render view]

I tried some suggestions I found in other answers, but they were hard to follow due to being for older versions of blender, and finding the similar settings here was hard/had no effect.

How can I get Blender to render the output normally? I don't see any layers that should obstruct, and even when I disable everything all I get is white, I can't find an "ambient" light setting that might bleed over everything. I tried changing the settings of rendering to color, opacity etc.. but it had no discernable effect. I tried moving the camera, ensuring my item is in field. I tried hiding the plane layer to see if that caused issues, but nothing I did seemed to have an effect on the rendering.

I'm using blender 2.90.1

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your world shader is the culprit.

The [*Background Shader*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/background.html?#background) has a strength of 500!

[image]

Change that to a more sane value, and you will see results more like you would expect.

Comment: Ah... I guess I messed up trying to do stuff with settings. Thanks!

Comment: It happens! Glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks to your help I managed to get this beauty :-) https://i.imgur.com/76d0NOc.png